# Using promises with chrome.runtime messaging system

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, es6-promise

In my chrome extension project, I'm using ES6 promises to get the result of XHR from the background page and send it to the content but I'm getting `undefined` as the value of `response` in the content. The XHR works fine, it returns a value.

BTW, queue.js is just my small sugar for ES6 promises.

queue.js

```
function defer() {
    let resolve = null;
    let reject = null;
    let promise = new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
        resolve = _resolve;
        reject = _reject;
    });

    return {
        'promise': promise,
        'resolve': resolve,
        'reject': reject
    };
}

module.exports = defer;
```

Content:

```
let Q = require('./queue');
let cb = Q();

function callback(response) {
    if (response) {
        let {result, data} = response;

        if (result === 'OK') {
            cb.resolve(data);

        } else if (result === 'KO') {
            cb.reject(data);
        }
    }
}

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    'event':'some_event',
    'data': {
        'user': 'test',
        'password': '1234'
    }
}, callback);

return cb.promise;
```

Background:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'I intentionally removed the URL to protect the innocent.',
        'method': 'POST',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'contentType': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'data': JSON.stringify({
            'username': message.data.user,
            'password': message.data.password
        })
    }).then((xhr) => {
        sendResponse({
            'result': 'OK',
            'data': xhr.token
        });
    }).fail((xhr) => {
        sendResponse({
            'result': 'KO',
            'data': null
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Note: I closed this as duplicate as there is a canonical question on the topic of `return true;` - but I also upvoted both, as it's a clean question and a good self-answer. It's worth keeping, even if pointed at the canonical Q.

Answer (score 12):

I've found the answer, in `developer.chrome.com`, `return true;` is needed in the `onMessage` so that chrome will recognise it as asynchronous. I don't know why this is the case since I called `sendResponse` inside the `then` of `$.ajax`